# change the state of a link after a click with Symfony

Tags: symfony5

hi everyone I'm having difficulties I have a page that displays the list of all the tontines available with a participate button to send a request here I would like that once we click on participate we will no longer have the possibility to click on it thank you

mon fichier twig
"'
{% for tont in tontines %}

```
<tr class="active">
<td>{{ tont.nomTontine }}</td>>
<td>{{ tont.descriptionTontine }}</td>
<td>{{ tont.dateDebut.format("d/m/Y") }}</td>
<td>{{ tont.dureeCouverte.format("d/m/Y") }}</td>
<td>{{ tont.montantPart }}fcfa</td>
<td>{{ tont.periodicite }}</td>
<td>{{ tont.createdAt.format("d/m/Y")}}</td>
{% for user in user %}
{% if tont.usersId== user.id %}
<td>{{ user.prenom }} {{ user.nom }}</td>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
    {% for part in part %}
    {% if part.nomTontine== tont.nomTontine and part.idUtilisateur %}
        <td><h6 class="btn btn-primary">Déjà demandé</h6></td>
    {% else %}
    <td> <a href="{{ path('participant' , {nomTontine: tont.nomTontine , usersId: tont.usersId}) }}" class="btn btn-info">Participer</a> </td>
    {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
```

{% endfor %}
'"

Comment: Should this apply within the session or permanently?

Comment: it applies permanently i don't use a session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can store the information in the Datebase
an entity with the Properies:

- button name:string
- isClickedBy:User[]

Then you need a logic, that checks if the Authenticated User is in the isClickedBy Array.

If you want the Information from User-Object too, you need a OneToMany relation.